# How do I update ELO ratings after a certain number of games played?

Tags: c++

I have a list of games played between two FIFA 19 players and wish to use that data to update my ELO ratings between the two players, according to the games played. I am trying to use this data to constantly update the ELO ratings that initially started off with a rating of 1000.

I tinkered with using pass by reference but not exactly sure how I should implement it as 2 different functions call the same rating variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

const int K = 20; //constant used in http://clubelo.com/Ranking

//tokenize and extract the number of goals only
vector <string> tokenize(string s){
    vector <string> tokens;
    stringstream check1(s);
    string intermediate;

    // Tokenizing w.r.t. space ' '
    while(getline(check1, intermediate, ' ')){
        tokens.push_back(intermediate);
    }

    return tokens;
}

//calculating goal difference to calculate ELO rating
int GoalDifference (int goalsA, int goalsB){
    int GoalDiff = abs(goalsA - goalsB);
    int G;

    if (GoalDiff == 0 || GoalDiff == 1)
        G = 1;
    else if (GoalDiff == 2)
        G = 3/2;
    else
        G = (11+GoalDiff)/8;

    return G;
}

//determine the result of the match by looking at goals
int result (int goalsA,int goalsB){
    int result;

    if (goalsA == goalsB)
        result = 0.5;
    else if (goalsA>goalsB)
        result = 1;
    else
        result = 0;

    return result;
}

// Function to calculate the Probability
float Probability(int rating1,int rating2){
    return 1.0 / (1.0 *pow(10, 1.0 * ((rating1 - rating2)) / 400)+1);
}

//calculating new ELO rating
int ELOratings (int rating, int goalsa, int goalsb, int probability){
    int deltapoints = K* GoalDifference(goalsa, goalsb) * (result(goalsa, goalsb) - probability);

    return rating + deltapoints;
}

int main(){
    int Ratinga = 1000, Ratingb = 1000;
    int goalsA, goalsB, probA, probB, ELOp1, ELOp2;

    ifstream inputFile;
    string input;
    inputFile.open("Scores of P1 vs P2.txt");
    vector <string> ScoreTokens;

    while (!inputFile.eof()) {
        getline(inputFile,input);
        ScoreTokens = tokenize(input);
        goalsA = stoi(ScoreTokens[1]);
        goalsB = stoi(ScoreTokens[3]);

        probA = Probability(Ratinga, Ratingb);
        probB = Probability(Ratingb, Ratinga);

        ELOp1 = ELOratings(Ratinga, goalsA, goalsB, probA);
        ELOp2 = ELOratings(Ratingb, goalsB, goalsA, probB);

        cout << "The new rating for P1 is: " << ELOp1 << endl;
        cout << "The new rating for P2 is: " << ELOp2 << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the scores and how I extracted the data: 
P1 VS P2
Liverpool 2 United 2 
Barca 2 Real 3

After calculations, after the first game, each should have a rating of 990. After the second game, P1 should be 970 and P2 should be 990.

But the actual output is 1000 after the first game.
After 2nd game:
P1: 1000
P2: 1020

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using integers everywhere for calculations that involve fractional numbers. For instance `3/2` is equal to `1`, (not `1.5`) because it's integer division and so the result is an integer.

Here's that function fixed

```
//calculating goal difference to calculate ELO rating
double GoalDifference (int goalsA, int goalsB){
    int GoalDiff = abs(goalsA - goalsB);
    double G;

    if (GoalDiff == 0 || GoalDiff == 1)
        G = 1.0;
    else if (GoalDiff == 2)
        G = 1.5;
    else
        G = (11+GoalDiff)/8.0;

    return G;
}
```

Note the return type has been changed to `double` as well, because the result is a fractional quantity. But the `goalsA` and `goalsB` has been left as integers because they really are integers.

Basically you need to go through your code and at each point ask yourself whether the number is an integer or a fraction and change appropriately.

BTW, both `float` and `double` can be used for fractions, but in general you should prefer `double` as it's more precise and no less efficient.